# Why is Medicare not included in the entities of policy change for CMS?

Tags: congress, health-insurance, medicaid, medicare

See this link.

https://www.medicaid.gov/federal-policy-guidance/index.html

Why is Medicare not included in this list?

The Centers for Medicare & Medicaid Services (CMS) is responsible for implementing laws passed by Congress related to `Medicaid, the Children’s Health Insurance Program (CHIP), and the Basic Health Program`. To implement these programs, CMS issues various forms of guidance to explain how laws will be implemented and what states and others need to do to comply. In addition to regulations, CMS issues sub-regulatory guidance to address policy issues as well as operational updates and technical clarifications of existing guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Medicare is financed and administered entirely by the federal government. Thus, CMS doesn't need to tell anyone else how the program should be administered, it just administers it itself as it sees fit.

Medicaid, the Children's Health Insurance Program (CHIP), and the Basic Health Program, are administered by state and local governments and financed with a combination of federal and state funds. Therefore, CMS needs to tell state and local governments how to administer these programs which CMS provides substantial funding for but doesn't run itself.